# How to rewrite subquery to return only 1 row

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, subquery

I need to somehow check if query result is `NULL`, MySQL returns error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. How should I rewrite it in order to work correctly please?

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.username, user.name, user.surname, user.avatar,
(SELECT IF(ISNULL(
  (SELECT attendant.fk_user AS u
  FROM attendant
  WHERE fk_event = 1

  UNION

  SELECT organizer.fk_user AS u
  FROM organizer
  WHERE fk_event = 1

  UNION

  SELECT invitation.fk_user_to AS u
  FROM invitation
  WHERE fk_event = 1)), NULL, 1)) AS related
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it after few hours of trying and googling. This post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708815/efficient-way-to-check-if-a-sql-query-will-return-results) was helpful. Instead of `IF` and `ISNULL` there should be used `CASE WHEN EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.username, user.name, user.surname, user.avatar,
CASE WHEN EXISTS
  (SELECT attendant.fk_user AS u
  FROM attendant
  WHERE fk_event = 1
  AND fk_user = `user`.id

  UNION

  SELECT organizer.fk_user AS u
  FROM organizer
  WHERE fk_event = 1
  AND fk_user = `user`.id

  UNION

  SELECT invitation.fk_user_to AS u
  FROM invitation
  WHERE fk_event = 1
  AND fk_user_to = `user`.id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS related
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your subquery select to count(*) e.g.

```
select o.OrderID, o.OrderAmount
from Orders o
where (select count(id) from Disputes d where d.CustomerID = o.CustomerID) <= 0
```

Comment: How could I select COUNT of UNION to return only one number from all 3 SELECTs?

Comment: @2rec you could nest them further.

Answer (score 1):

Or a little bit simpler is to use "WHERE EXISTS".

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_type FROM stores
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cities_stores
WHERE cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type);
```

For details see:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

And for the subqueries use

FROM ( subquery1 union subqueryN) AS related